# Did 9/11 occur in the House of Cards universe?

Tags: house-of-cards

Season 4 of House of Cards features the terrorist organisation 'ICO' (Islamic Caliphate Organisation - essentially ISIS).

**Season 4 spoiler:**

> At the end of the season, Frank and Claire use a terrorist kidnapping to declare war on terror, as a means to stay in power.

My question is - do the events of House of Cards take place in an America where 9/11 has happened ~10 years prior?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is a reference to 9/11 at the end of Season 4's seventh episode.

Frank Underwood is remembering a meeting with Governor Conway. In the remembered scene, Frank asks if it's true Governor Conway had joined the U.S. military after the events of 9/11. The governor responds:

> "You want a career in politics and the Twin Towers fall in your lap?
>   The timing couldn't have been better"

(Full disclosure: I found the answer above within the answer to [another question about House of Cards here on StackExchange](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/50448/what-did-frank-and-claire-realize-after-watching-governor-conways-video?rq=1))

Comment: Ahhh of course, it's a fairly major plot point.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Early in [S04E07](https://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/view_episode_scripts.php?tv-show=house-of-cards-2013&episode=s04e07), Conway to a crowd:

> You know what I did when 9/11 happened? I joined the Air Force because I wanted to serve my country, just like my grandfather did when he boarded a transport ship on this very dock and sailed to the Pacific to fight the Japanese.

Near the end of the same episode, there is a flashback to the 2013 New Year Party (when Walker was still the President-Elect):

> Frank Underwood: So, is it true that you joined up a day after 9/11, or is that just something you say?
>
> Conway: Within 24 hours, honest to God.
>
> Underwood: That's incredible.
>
> Conway: Hey I was 25, just out of law school. You want a career in politics and the Twin Towers fall in your lap? Timing couldn't have been better.
>
> ...
>
> Underwood: How old are you? 35?
>
> Conway: 36.

If the numbers are all correct, assuming Conway's birthday is between January 1 and September 11, and assuming the usual western/American convention of counting ages, one can conclude that the in-universe 9/11 also took place in 2001.